# Group of groups of radio buttons with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects that have internal array of objects, I need some groups according to number of parent objects that have group of radio buttons according to number of child objects

This array is somth like this:

```
ctrl.objects = [
                {
                    name: "name",
                    numbers: [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "number": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "number": 2
                        },
                         {
                            "id": 2,
                            "number": 3
                        },
                    ],
                    "age": "20"
                },
                {
                    name: "name1",
                    numbers: [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "number": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "number": 20
                        },
                         {
                            "id": 2,
                            "number": 30
                        },
                    ],
                    "age": "25"
                },
            ];
```

And there is a template

```
<div ng-repeat="object in ctrl.objects">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>{{object.name}}</legend>
                        <div ng-repeat="objectInfo in object.numbers">
                            <div class="nxn-radio">
                                <input type="radio"
                                       value="{{objectInfo.number}}"
                                       id="{{objectInfo.number}}"
                                       name="{{object.name}}"
                                       ng-model="ctrl.objectInfoData">
                                <label for="{{objectInfo.number}}">
                                    <strong>{{objectInfo.number}}</strong>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

At the end I have 2 groups with 3 radios in each one but all radios are in one group (I can chose 1 number from 6 variant but need 1 from first 3 radios and one from second 3 radios)

And finally I need an array of ids of chosen numbers => ['0', '1'] for chosen 1 and 20

Can somebody help to resovle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same model for all your inputs. Changing any input will change the model, which will update all other inputs. You need one model per name.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wy7e98bd/

Js:

```
$scope.ctrl = {objectInfoData: {}}
```

HTML:

```
ng-model="ctrl.objectInfoData[object.name]"
```